# Member Objects as unique_ptr or on Stack

Tags: c++, member, unique-ptr

Currently i am thinking about storing some member objects in unique_ptr.
Normally i use unique_ptr just in some functions and move it around, or pass references to it.
So how should i do in classes?

```
Class MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<MyMemberClass> member;
}
```

or:

```
Class MyClass {
    MyMemberClass member;
}
```

The lifetime of the object is the same. The initialization in the constructor would be nearly the same.
The only difference is, that i can't copy the unique_ptr, or?

Are there other differences?
And which should i use or prefer?

Comment: The second doesn't store `member` "on the stack", it stores it where ever the `MyClass` object is stored, which might be the stack, but might also be anywhere else.

Comment: Why "class" keyword start with capital letter?

Comment: @PaoloM: The `class` keyword doesn't start with a capital letter. However, the OP's code contains the word `Class` starting with a capital letter...

Comment: Unique pointer members are a common idiom for pimpl and dependency injection, i.e. situations where the precise content of an object is provided by the caller.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there other differences? And which should i use or prefer?

Yes.

The deciding factors here are:

- **polymorphic behavior** : If you store the common interface for a class hierarchy, then you should store by pointer, smart pointer or reference.
- **lifetime** : as you mentioned, if the held object has a longer lifetime than `MyClass` (and obviously, it is not owned by `MyClass`) then it should be held in a raw pointer or a std::shared_ptr.
- **ownership** : if the object is not owned by `MyClass`, then it should be stored as a pointer (smart or not) or a reference.
- **api constraints**: if the held object is generated by a library that can only allocate it dynamically (for example), then you will probably want to hold it in a pointer (or unique_ptr).

When the object is owned (exclussively) by `MyClass`, it has the same lifetime as the owning class, and you do not have polymorphic behavior, you should probably store the instance directly.

Answer (score 0):

Differences:

1) You can't copy class with `unique_ptr` (you can actually, but this has no sense), but you can move.

2) If `member` is `unique_ptr`, `MyMemberClass` object should be allocated on heap, when in second case it's allocated on stack (when object of type `MyClass` is allocated on stack).

3) If `member` is complicated object, than probably store pointer on it is better, in other case just object is fine.

4) If `member` is `unique_ptr` it can be a polymorphic object. It allows to create an aggregate object. With the second form it is not possible (thanks to chmike).

Comment: Add to this that with unique_ptr, `member` can be a polymorphic object. It allows to create an aggregate object. With the second form it is not possible.

Comment: @chmike 3) If member is complicated object, than probably store pointer on it is better, in other case just object is fine can you explain why?

Comment: I would say it is to minimize the code to recompile if you modify the complex class of the member object. The class complexity increases the probability of a later change.